# Receiving this error when running 'npm start' on my React app

Tags: reactjs, npm, openssl, npm-start

I'm getting back into web development after a break.

When I run 'npm start'

I am receiving this error

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:449:10)
    at /Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:481:5
    at /Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:342:12
    at /Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
/Users/emma/Documents/prototype-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^
```

I have tried to figure out what is causing this and have cleaned the npm cache and reinstalled but I'm feeling quite confused with what the root cause of the error is and how to fix it.

I have done some Googling which said that the OpenSSL error related to "unsupported" digital envelope routines could be linked to system-specific issues or conflicts with dependencies.

Any advice on this would be appreciated because I am not sure how to fix it at the moment.

Comment: can you poast what you have in your `package.json`? Also, do you know the Node version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have reinstalled and cleared the npm cache, but have you tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then reinstalling? This essentially wipes the slate clean and installs new versions of your project's dependencies, which can sometimes resolve conflicts or issues when running a project.

## **Delete the node_modules Directory**

The `node_modules` directory contains all the packages and libraries and their dependencies that your project relies on. Sometimes deleting it removes this potential source of errors.

Run `rm -rf node_modules` to delete the folder in your terminal at your project root.

## **Delete package-lock.json**

The `package-lock.json` file is automatically generated for all operations when npm modifies either the `node_modules` tree or the `package.json` file. It describes the exact tree that was generated so that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees. Deleting this file could solve problems with dependency versions or configurations.

Still in your project's root directory, run `rm package-lock.json` to delete the file.

## **Run npm install**

After deleting both of those, run `npm install` again. If you are using a development server, remember to restart it.

*Side note:*
If you are not comfortable with running commands in your terminal, simply right clicking and deleting them in your code editor will suffice. Then run `npm install` again. I hope this helps you